# it says "RESTART: C:\python\python ex\facebook EX.py" nothing else

Tags: python, restart

```
import sys
import urllib.request
import json

if __name__ == '_main_':

    # [CODE1]
    page_name = "jtbnews"
    app_id = "[App ID]"
    app_secret = "[App Secret Code]"
    access_token = app_id + "I" +app_secret
    # [CODE2]
    # http://graph.facebook.com/v2.8/[page_id]/?access_token=[App_ID]I[Secret_Key]
    # 형식의 문자열을 만들어 낸다.
    base = "http://graph.facebook.com/v2.8"
    node = "/" + page_name
    parameters = "/?access_token=%s" % access_token
    url = base + node + parameters
    # [CODE3]
    req = urllib.request.Request(url)
    # [CODE4]
    try:
        response = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
        if response.getcode() == 200:
            data = json.loads(response.read().decode('utf-8'))
            page_id = data['id']
            print("%s Facebook numeric ID : %s" % (page_name, page_id))
    except Exception as e: print(e)
```

I'm a 100% beginner of programming
I follow the code in a book. 
I can't figure out what is the problem. 
it just says:

```
"RESTART: C:\python\python ex\facebook EX.py"
```

Comment: If `response.getcode()` is not equal to 200 you won't get any output.  So maybe add `print('Response status is', response.getcode())` before the `if` statement to see the value.

Comment: Are you using replacing the string "[App ID]" and "[App Secret Code]" with your actual values when running the code. Those are just placeholders in the book and you have to use your own values you get from Facebook API